# c# compare DateTime start and DateTime stop with List<DateTime>

Tags: c#, datetime

Like the title says:

I have a `DateTime start` and  a `DateTime stop`

Now i want to compare these with a `List<DateTime> dates`

I just wanto check if the list `dates` is between `start` and `stop`

`if(dates.all(..... >= start && <= stop)) {
. do something
}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pseudo-code in your question is not far from the working code you're looking for.

Using LINQ's [All()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) method:

```
if (dates.All(date => date >= start && date <= stop)) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sort the list.
Check if the first item in the list is >= start date and last item in the list <= end date

Comment: Wouldn't sorting the list would typically take longer than a single-pass mindate/maxdate check?

Comment: @Frosty840 - Yep it would, but thats what my neurons came up with in few seconds of time :)

Answer (score 2):

With linq: `if(dates.All(d => d >= start && d <= stop))`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `All` extension method, and a lambda expression that does the comparison:

```
if (dates.All(d => d >= start && d <= stop)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Incase you want to iterate just the dates in the bracket, you can use the following:

```
foreach (DateTime date in dates.Where(o => o >= start && o <= stop))
{
    //Do your thing.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work on it like

```
bool allTrue = LstDates.TrueForAll(delegate(DateTime dt) { return dt >= startDate && dt <= endDate; });
```